# How do I create a Qml component from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I tried to use QQmlComponent component(view.engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml")); and then QOObject *object = component.create(); but it gives me Qml Component not ready. Further tried to connect the statusChanged signal to a slot function, but it doesnt seem to load the new qml components.

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QQmlComponent component(view.engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
QObject *object = component.create();
object->setParent(view.rootObject());
view.show()
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *rootObj = view.rootObject();                                            QQmlComponent component(view.engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));

    QObject *object = component.create();
     
     object->setParent(view.rootObject());
    view.show()

Comment: I've also tried it by creating a class VViewerQml, in the constructor of the class,  _view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
     connect(&_view, SIGNAL(statusChanged(QQuickView::Status)), this, SLOT(onViewStatusChanged(QQuickView::Status)));

     _view.show(); and in the slot onViewStatusChanged(QQuickView::Status status) {if (status)
   {

    QQmlComponent *c = new QQmlComponent(_view.engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));

    QQuickItem *i = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(c->create());  QQuickItem *i = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(c->create()); // add i to view.rootObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading from a local file, then set the `QQmlComponent` to load synchronously by specifying it in the constructor:

```
QQmlComponent component(view.engine(),
                        QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"),
                        QQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous );
```

Comment: I tried addingQQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous to the constructor but it doesnt seem to work. The program hangs and gives me QQmlComponent: Not ready. The problem is compounded with the fact that onViewStatusChanged, the slot triggered by statusChanged is not even called.

Comment: The program _hangs_!?  There's something else wrong with your code.  You need to post more of it, including `MyItem.qml`.

Comment: MyItem.qml import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 362

     Text {
         text: "Hello World!"
           font.family: "Helvetica"
           font.pointSize: 24
           color: "red"
     }

     TextEdit {
         width:50
         height:60
        x:50
        y:200
     }
} The program tries to create a component for this qml and it hangs because the qqml component is not ready and it cannot be created.

Comment: @CartikSharma You don't seem to understand, you have a local file that is  _tiny_ and you are saying that `QQmlComponent` is hanging whilst loading it - this sounds implausible.  Step through the code with your debugger and find exactly which line it breaks on.  I suspect that your QML file is failing to load due to errors, so the `createObject(..)` call returns a nullptr leading to a segfault.

Comment: I stepped through the debugger, the program crashes when it reaches the line, i->setParent(_view->rootObject()); where i is QQuickItem,  QQmlComponent *c = new QQmlComponent(_view->engine(), QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));                                          QQuickItem *i = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(c->create()); what should I setParent to? P.S I also get QQmlComponent not ready.

Comment: I removed QQuickItem and simply did a create for QQmlComponent and it doesnt crash, I'm setting parent to _view->rootObject(). Nothing appears on the screen though and I still get QQmlComponent not ready.

Comment: @CartikSharma Have you checked `QQmlComponent::errors()`?

Comment: I tried c->errors() for the QQmlComponent and it told me the path for the MyItem.qml file was not correct so it wasnt seeing the file! Guess it's fixed and it works now, thanks!

Comment: @CartikSharma If this has worked for you then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Interacting with QML Objects from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html).

> Loading QML Objects from C++
>
> A QML document can be loaded with QQmlComponent or QQuickView. QQmlComponent loads a QML document as a C++ object that can then be modified from C++ code. QQuickView also does this, but as QQuickView is a QWindow-derived class, the loaded object will also be rendered into a visual display; QQuickView is generally used to integrate a displayable QML object into an application's user interface.
>
> ...

Also, more wide topic [Integrating QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html).